# How to dynamically autoSize a sharepoint modal dialog box?

Tags: sharepoint

I've created a web application in sharepoint which has a sign in link which loads a login webpart in the modal window on click. I haven't set the height of the modal pop through options but i have set its width only.

IE 7, 8 and 9 loads the webpart as per my need, and it automatically adjusts its height on load.  But Firefox (din't test in Chrome) loads the webpart but the height is not adjusted automatically to fit the login WP.

I tried using SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().autoSize() explicitly like below

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().autoSize();
}, "sp.ui.dialog.js");
```

But this also does not work for Firefox. Calling autoSize in IE works great when I display the errors on login screen but on FF it returns height to be less than 20px and the modal popup seems to have a width but its height is less than 20.

How do I solve this issue?

Please help.

Sorry if I looked like a noob to all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your web part have a height definition?

Comment: no.. it doesnt.. i have only width set. height is made to automatically choose it based on the content tat loads inside the modal popup

Answer (score 3):

I was just trying to work through a simliar problem myself. I wanted to override the width because my content was wrapping in an undesired behavior. I found that the following allows me to adjust the width after the dialog is presented.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
  var dialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog();
  dialog.$2_0.autoSizeStartWidth = 1100;
  dialog.autoSize();
}, "sp.ui.dialog.js");
```

I just added that into a script editor webpart as part of the display form part and it works like a dream.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the property autoSize **before** creating the dialog:

```
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.autoSize = true;
...
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: no. it has a height of 8px or something when I checked in Firebug.

Comment: 8px is the height of ms-dlgContent?

Comment: Does your pop up page contain classes named 's4-ribbonrow' and 's4-workspace'?

Comment: @ 1st question: 10px is the height of the ms-dlgContent and the remaining divs have 8px height.

Comment: @ 2nd question: yes s4-ribbonrow is made display none and s4-workspace is display block with a height of 8px.

Comment: So the problem is that s4-workspace has a height of 8px. 1) does is have a height definition? 2) its content is larger than 8px?

Comment: 1) no it is not given a height definition
2) yes inside that is where the web part gets loaded. and once the webpart loads, I call the autoSize () function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22806/discussion-between-banana-and-abhilash-lr)

Comment: What was your fix/resolution? I have been banging my head for hours on this and the link to your chat no longer exists...

Comment: @danda1man - He did not respond to my invitation to chat, so there was no fix.
If you want - I can try to check what is the problem in your case.

Comment: Firefox 20.0.1, on my machine worked fine, the boxes resized and there wasn't any issue.  When we went to QA, the testers on the exact same version of Firefox got modals that had a 0 height so the content wasn't visible.  Calling the resize function had no affect and the box stayed the same size.  We all uninstalled and reinstalled firefox but got the same results.  I think the only difference was that i was running windows 8 and they were on 7.  Seems like it would be a firefox bug and not a SharePoint bug, but that is apparently not an acceptable answer...

Comment: @danda1man - To be honest, I have not tried it on windows 8.
I think that the only way you can find out what is causing the problem - is to debug the function AutoSize.
The file where the function located: _layouts / sp.ui.dialog.debug.js.
(In my file - this function starts in row 554.)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but for some reason autoSize() was not working for me, so I started digging and I wrote workaround for resizing modal window height after it is shown, using jQuery.

```
var dlg = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog();
var header = $(dlg.$I_0)
var userRoot = $(dlg.$L_0);
var frameContainer = $(dlg.$1Z_0);

var headerContentHeight = header.height();
var headerMargin = header.cssUnit("margin")[0] * 2;
var headerPadding = header.cssUnit("padding")[0] * 2;
var headerHeight = headerContentHeight + headerMargin + headerPadding;
var frameContainerPadding = Math.ceil(($(dlg.$7_0).height() - userRoot.height() - headerHeight) / 2);

//frame container
$(dlg.$1Z_0).height(height - headerHeight - frameContainerPadding);

//background white space
$(dlg.$4_0).height(height);

//border
$(dlg.$1H_0).height(height);

//root of user html
userRoot.height(height - headerHeight - frameContainerPadding);

//frame
$(dlg.$7_0).height(height);

//center the window
$('.ms-dlgContent').css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + ((($(window).height() - $('.ms-dlgContent').height()) / 2) - 30) + "px");
```

Keep in mind that the actual height of the window is larger than the the one in the dialog options. This function will set the actual height of the dialog window to match the new height.

Maybe this solution could help anyone else, having this problem. This is all modifying the styles, so it should not be a problem, but it is kind of a "hack" so it could be buggy.